# Uploading and storing an image in Laravel 5.8 image not storing in database or file path

Tags: php, laravel

Fairly new to laravel I want to upload an image and store it in the database and file path. First issue I am having is the image is not appearing in the array for the **validateRequest** function so it is returning as NULL in the database. Second issue is I tried to use **storage:link** to store all the uploaded images but can't seem to store the images and unsure what file path I meant to use.

```
    public function validateRequest()
    {
        $validated = request()->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string',
            'h1' => 'required|string',
            'page_title' => 'required|string',
            'meta_description' => 'required|string',
            'content' => 'required|string',
            'active' => 'integer'
        ]);

        if (request()->hasFile('image')){
            $validated = request()->validate([
                'image' => 'sometimes|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:5000'
            ]);
        }

        // Check if active is ticked
        $validated['active'] = isset(request()->active[0]) ? 1 : 0;

        // Create slug from title
        $validated['slug'] = Str::slug(request()['title'], '-');

        return $validated;
    }
```

```
    public function storeImage($post)
    {
        if (request()->hasFile('image')) {
            $post->update([
                'image' => request()->image->storeAs('/images/uploads/posts', 'public')
            ]);

        }
    }
```

I have tried putting the image with the rest of the fields in the `$validated = request()->validate` but then it says "this image must be an image" even though an image has been selected. Really appreciate the help thank you.

Comment: can you share with us your code of form on front end ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is validate. Please add this in your `form`

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Second problem is to solve like this. In your controller call function like this

```
$productImage = $request->file('your_image_name');

if (is_file($productImage)) {
    $imageUrl = $this->productImageUpload($productImage);
    $product->your_database_field_name = $imageUrl;
}


protected function productImageUpload($productImage)
{
    $imageName = $productImage->getClientOriginalName();
    $directory = 'your_file_path/your_file_path/';
    $imageUrl = $directory . $imageName;
    $productImage->move($directory, $imageName);
    return $imageUrl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I realised hadn't used enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form. Also now I know storage link creates the file path of where the images are stored. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are most welcome. Its my pleasure to contribute little bit help you